# Gwt ClientBundle can't find images

Tags: gwt, gwt2

A ClientBundle works fine in my main project: `com.example.project.client.Bundle`

Another ClientBundle in my library compiles into a jar just fine: `com.example.library.client.Bundle`

Compiling my project when it depends on the library fails:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/work/library.jar!/com/example/library/client/Bundle.java'
[ERROR] Line 10:  Failed to resolve 'com.example.library.client.Bundle' via deferred binding
```

I've checked the library jar, and the image files are at `/com/example/library/client/` as they were in the library's source. Is there some trick? I've tried referencing the images both with `@ClientBundle.Source("com/example/library/client/icon.gif")` and `@ClientBundle.Source("icon.gif")`, both of which allow the library to compile file, but fail when compiling the depending project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was my fault. I was referencing icon.gif but actually had icon.png in the filesystem. Simple typo.

My big mistake was confusing the compilation steps. When you have a GWT library, and compile it into a jar, you're **not** doing a GWT compile. So you're not actually verifying any of the ClientBundle annotations. That verification doesn't happen until a depending project does a full GWT compile (and that's where it was failing for me)